# Как сделать вот такой дизайн?

Tags: html, css

как сделать вот такой дизайн?
есть вот так:[image: Єсть]

а нужно вот так:
[image: как нужно]

типа чтоб фотка взяла цвет своего фона из цвета body

Comment: Нужно просто отрисовать нужный уровень прозрачности в любом графическом редакторе, html и css тут вообще ни при чём. А вообще, если это из какого-то векторного макета, нужно было изначально делать экспорт картинки на прозрачном, а не на белом фоне, чтобы не страдать теперь

Comment: Или можно даже просто загуглить — в интернете уже есть [эта картинка с прозрачным фоном](https://res2.weblium.site/res/5c3499549422180022513a78/5c3ca8a5229b6d002262451d_optimized_800_c800x800-0x0?nowebp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.back {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 32px;
}

.back img {
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <img src="https://res2.weblium.site/res/5c3499549422180022513a78/5c3ca8a5229b6d002262451d_optimized_800_c800x800-0x0?nowebp">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная картинка должна быть с transparency (прозрачность). 
Тогда фон будет тот, который вы хотите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: почему не работает ? у  вас как css  описывает   html  элемент ?  должно быть  так   ..... class .my class  # body  bgcolor="black",  image - image.png

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).